# Selecting with NOT IN and Many to Many relationship

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have a many to many relationship

```
--------------------
| user_id | name   |
--------------------
| 1       | user1  |
--------------------
| 2       | user2  |
--------------------
| 3       | user3  |
--------------------


--------------------
| type_id | name   |
--------------------
| 1       | type1  |
--------------------
| 2       | type2  |
--------------------
| 3       | type3  |
--------------------

---------------------
| user_id | type_id |
---------------------
| 1       | 1       |
---------------------
| 1       | 2       |
---------------------
| 1       | 3       |
---------------------
| 2       | 1       |
---------------------
| 2       | 2       |
---------------------
| 3       | 3       |
---------------------
```

I'm trying to construct a query so that if I user is of type 3, do not return that user at all. So far I have a query that excludes users who are of type 3, but they are being returned if other types are also assigned to them.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `t`.`user_id`) 
FROM `user` `t` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `type` `type_type` ON (`t`.`user_id`=`type_type`.`user_id`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `type` `type` ON (`type`.`type_id`=`type_type`.`type_id`) 
WHERE ((type.type_ids NOT IN (3));
```

the above query will still return `user_id 1` because that user is assigned to multiple types, how do I eliminate users of type 3, no matter how many other types they are assigned to?

Comment: the number of types in that query hurts my eyes. usually you try and make column names unique across different tables especially if they are related. I would change the "name" column to "user_name" and "type_name" respectively.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this for your `where` clause:

```
where t.user_id not in (select user_id from usertypes where type_id = 3)
```

In MySQL, the following may be more efficient:

```
where not exists (select 1 from usertypes ut where ut.type_id = 3 and ut.user_id = t.user_id)
```

By the way "t" is a lousy alias for `users`, especially when you are using another table called `types`.  "u" would be a better alias.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to use a join instead of not in?

Comment: @nathanhayfield . . . I find the `not in` version the most intuitive, especially because that is what the question started with.  The `not exists` version is likely to be the most efficient.

Comment: totally +1 for where not exists

Answer (score 5):

Your `IN()` subquery needs to return the `user_id`s which have a `type_id = 3`.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT `t`.`user_id`)
FROM 
 `user` `t` 
WHERE `user_id NOT IN (SELECT `user_id` FROM `type_type` WHERE `type_id` = 3)
```

It can also be done using a `LEFT JOIN` against the same subquery, looking for `NULL`s in the `type_type` table.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT `t`.`user_id`)
FROM 
 `user` `t` 
 LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT `user_id` FROM `type_type` WHERE `type_id` = 3
 ) user3 ON t.user_id = user3.user_id
WHERE user3.type_id IS NULL
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b36b1/7

Actually the joined subquery isn't even necessary. It will work with a plain `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT `t`.`user_id`)
FROM 
 `user` `t` 
 LEFT JOIN type_type ON t.user_id = type_type.user_id AND type_type.type_id = 3
WHERE type_type.type_id IS NULL
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b36b1/10

Comment: I prefer the version where you don't need a subquery.

Comment: Awesome. Many thanks. This should be definitively the accepted answer.